# How do I read the output of the IPython %prun (profiler) command?

Tags: python, interpreter, profiler, ipython

I run this:

```
In [303]: %prun my_function()
         384707 function calls (378009 primitive calls) in 83.116 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    37706   41.693    0.001   41.693    0.001 {max}
    20039   36.000    0.002   36.000    0.002 {min}
    18835    1.848    0.000    2.208    0.000 helper.py:119(fftfreq)
```

--snip--

What do each of tottime, percall, cumtime? ncalls is fairly obviously (number of times the function is called). My *guess* is that tottime is the total time spent in the function excluding time spent within its own function calls; percall is ???; cumtime is total time spent in the function call including time spent within its own function calls (but of course, excluding double counting). The [docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magic.html#IPython.core.magic.Magic.magic_prun) are not too helpful; Google search doesn't help either.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's just a convenient wrapper for Python's own profiler, the documentation for which is here:

http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-pstats

Quoting:

> **ncalls**
>   for the number of calls,
>
> **tottime** for the total time spent in the given function (and excluding time made in calls to sub-functions),
>
> **percall** is the quotient of tottime divided by ncalls
>
> **cumtime** is the total time spent in this and all subfunctions (from invocation till exit). This figure is accurate even for recursive
>   functions.
>
> **percall** is the quotient of cumtime divided by primitive calls

Comment: how is it possible that a method that only calls other methods have a significant `tottime` ?